# Jenkins build not executing `docker tag` command correctly

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, ansible, ansible-awx

I am attempting to build https://github.com/ansible/awx.

To setup my Jenkins environment, I deployed Ubuntu in AWS, installed the development tools, docker, and Jenkins, and joined the jenkins user to the docker group. Then, I setup Jenkins with the default configuration.

After Jenkins was setup, I created a "freestyle project," set the SCM git repository URL to https://github.com/ansible/awx.git, then added an execute shell build step to the following:

```
cp awx/settings/local_settings.py.docker_compose awx/settings/local_settings.py
make docker-compose-build
```

Build. Fairly simple, right?! No. The build creates a docker image as it is supposed to. However, the final command of the Makefile is to tag docker image using the following command:

```
docker tag ansible/awx_devel gcr.io/ansible-tower-engineering/awx_devel:origin/devel
```

However, this returns the following:

```
Error parsing reference: "gcr.io/ansible-tower-engineering/awx_devel:origin/devel" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

This error does NOT happen if I run the make command in a similar environment. It does NOT happen if I run the docker tag command in a similar environment.

P.S. I have tried explicitly setting the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

So, the problem is `/` in your tag name. Try tagging with `origin-devel`.

Comment: This is it. When I run the build manually, the command this is run is actually: `docker tag ansible/awx_devel gcr.io/ansible-tower-engineering/awx_devel:HEAD`.
The tag is generated by `$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`. Any idea why this would run differently in Jenkins?

Comment: In the end, the issue was environment conflict. Jenkins set the GIT_BRANCH to `origin/devel` instead of `devel`.